# What does 足元をうろちょろする mean?

Tags: meaning

I’m reading 『魔女の宅急便2キキと新しい魔法』.　There’s a sentence about Kiki (a witch who’s the main character of this book) and Jiji (Kiki’s cat who can talk with her) saying:

> キキは安心したようにマルコさん(というカバ)を見、それから、**足元を心配顔でうろちょろしている**ジジに「しっぽって、そういうもの？」とききました。ジジはだまって、自分のしっぽをつんと立てました。

I’m not sure what this phrase means, between

A: Jiji walking around the floor with worried face.

or

B: Jiji walking around Kiki’s legs (and letting his body touch her legs) with worried face.

Answer (score 1):

It is A. For example, [this dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E8%B6%B3%E4%B8%8B/#je-945) entry has 足の周辺 (足元/足下 are the same). So Jiji is walking restlessly near her feet, not necessarily sticking to them.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness :)